# jQuery $ not defined - Issues using window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a `$ not defined error` in the second case below, but not the first.  jQuery is installed and working on the site.

Any code using `$` in here runs fine:

```
jQuery(function($) {  
  alert("Yay!");
});
```

Anything inside of this errors with `$ not a function`:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) { 
  alert("Why not!");
});
```

Comment: Please provide more info. This seems to be a Namespacing issue. What does your `<head>` details look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because the [`load()` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/#load-handler) does not accept a jQuery object as an argument as `document.ready` (which is what your first example is shorthand for) does. In the second example your `$` variable is actually a reference to the Event object, as such you're probably calling methods which don't exist.

If you want to use `$` to reference jQuery, then it should be available by default. If for whatever reason it isn't, for example if you're using Wordpress, then you can use `jQuery.noConflict()` or an IIFE to re-alias it.

It's also worth noting that `load()` is deprecated. To hook to the `window.load` event use `on()`:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  // your logic here...
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Still learning over here, so I really appreciate the details. :)